# Azure App Service Enviroment - how to assign different IPs to app services

Tags: azure, ip, app-service-environment

I have created an Azure App Service Environment with 4 IP Addresses but all of them are unassigned. I have a bunch of app services and I need to have one IP per app service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to **upload a SSL certificate** (you can buy it in Azure portal or from any other company), **import it and bind it**. When you bind it you say it's an **IP Based SSL**. After you save you get a dedicated IP for that app service.

More on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site